# Why Java (Eclipse) shows an error indicating 160.934 is a boolean?

Tags: junit

for the line of assert below, Eclipse gives an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to boolean. Anyone knows why?

```
public class ConversionImplTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ConversionImpl conversionImpl = new ConversionImpl();
        double result = conversionImpl.milesToKilometers(100);
        assert(result = 160.934);
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Please try this:

double result = 99.99;
assert(result == 66.66);
The test is successful. Why?

Comment: = is assignment, == is comparison

Comment: `assert` expects a boolean and you're passing it a double.

Comment: Additionally, it's not a JUnit assertion, and you shouldn't use equality comparison with floating point.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be `result == 160.934` instead of `result = 160.934`

Comment: assert(result == 20) also passed, while the actual result value is 160.934;

Comment: Let me know if you get the same result if you clean all and build again your project.

Comment: double result = 99.99;
  assert(result == 0);

Comment: @user3335598 I tried it and everything was fine. No Idea what's wrong with you code.the only thing that I thought might cause problem was build process that you are sure it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that **assert** is a Java keyword, not a JUnit method, and as such it is normally ignored unless you specify -ea on the command line. JUnit runs do not normally specifiy this argument to the JVM.

Comment: His question is why the test passed when the result of the comparison was false. I am trying to explain that the comparison was ignore if it was not run with the -ea command line argument.